# What are the five most commonly used real-time operating systems?

Tags: operating-system, real-time, rtos

I am looking for mostly used 5 Real-Time operating systems. I searched on Google and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_real-time_operating_systems) has a list of RTOSs, but they are in random order and also I am not convinced that all of them really operating real-time.

One more question: can we include Windows 7? When we set priority of 5 tasks, for example to realtime.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based / too broad / tool rec.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Real-time operating systems that I have come in contact with, in order of (subjective) impact:

- VxWorks
- QNX
- eCos
- RTLinux

Especially VxWorks has a long history in critical applications - for example, in cars and various NASA space platforms. It is however neither free nor open source software - I would probably prefer eCos or RTLinux in one of my own projects.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) also has a [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system#Examples) with what is supposedly a list of the most deployed RTOS, although its contents are not supported by any references.

That said, if you search around a bit you will find that the most deployed RTOS are usually found in proprietary embedded systems. Many of those actually push the definition of an Operating System quite a bit (e.g. the various [exokernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exokernel) designs out there).

Without more informaton on your use of this list, we cannot provide more information. If you intend to develop RT software, for example, there are far more factors to consider than the popularity of each RTOS. Cost, supported hardware, familiarity with the various interfaces, vendor support for specific applications, quality of the development tools etc. should all be taken into account...

Answer (score 5):

Out of Wikipedia's long list, the names I recognized as "deployed" amongst people I know:

eCos, LynxOS, QNX, RTAI, RTLinux, Symbian OS, VxWorks, Windows CE, MontaVista Linux.

Of these, I'd guess this order: Symbian OS, Windows CE, QNX, MontaVista, RTLinux. But those are my guesses. :)

If you want to include Soft Real-Time systems, Windows 7 and stock Linux might qualify. Depends upon your needs.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but an anecdotal opinion.  Why is it "accepted"?

Answer (score 4):

VDC do an annual survey of the embedded system market which would no doubt answer your question; you have to pay for the full report, but you can get the [executive brief](http://www.vdcresearch.com/market_research/embedded_software/product_detail.aspx?productid=2627) for free if you register.

From other sources: 
In 2006 of the commercial RTOS vendors the following led:

- VxWorks
- XP Embedded
- Windows CE
- DSP/BIOS
- Red Hat Linux

Now, these are from [survey responses](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/other/4025674/Operating-systems-on-the-rise), and some of these I would not consider Real-Time, so if you weed out the non-real-time OSs, I would say:

- VxWorks
- Windows CE
- DSP/BIOS
- QNX
- RTX

But survey response is not divided by platform type; what is appropriate to an 8 bit system, or a deeply embedded system with no need for file-systems, networking, or display etc. are very different.  And if you have never used a TI DSP, you'd never have even encountered DSP/BIOS before.  So the question itself is probably too simplistic to answer, since to get meaningful results you probably have to specify the target platform and application complexity.

The survey also does not consider non-commercial RTOS such as FreeRTOS, RTEMS, and eCOS.  These are very worthy of consideration and in some cases of superior quality to some commercial systems.  In 2009 for example FreeRTOS was [downloaded more than 77500 times](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/guest-editor/4027638/Buy-or-roll-your-own-OS-Neither-with-FreeRTOS-), and eCOS has extensive support for file-systems and networking etc.  Of course no one can tell how many such RTOSes are *used* in real products or simply by hobbyists or even downloaded and never used.

Another question is whether you are interested in *volume* of product or number of distinct *projects*?  For example WidgetA may incorporate say Keil RTX bundled free with its ARM-MDK, and sell in millions, while PABX-Exchange-B, may use VxWorks costing tens of thousands in royalties and development licences, but sell in the few tens.  The comparison is pointless.

Comment: Can you also list the ones used in the automotive industry?

Comment: @ObaidMaroof:  This question is over a year old, and did not ask specifically for automotive; do your own research or post a specific question yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The choice of the RTOS strongly depends on the application domain. In each application domain (e.g., avionics, automotive, military) there is a leader. Also, because each application domain has different certification rules (e.g., OSEK/AUTOSAR in automotive, DO-178B in avionics, etc.) and some RTOSs have not been certified for all the standards.

In my experience, WindRiver VxWorks is the most used across all application domains.

But I know companies using GreenHills Integrity (avionics), Windows CE 6 (consumer), LynxOS (military) Vector and [Erika Enterprise](http://erika-enterprise.com) (automotive).

Answer (score 1):

what about Green Hills Integrity - in their eyes they are the No 1 independant RTOS vendor, implying that Wind River is no longer independent as owned by Intel.  They also have ENEA as No 2, but this seems based on revenue.

Answer (score 0):

we can also add ERCOS(Embedded Real time control Operating System based on OSEK standad) RTOS in the list. It is widely used in automotive industry but vrutually unknown to many people. Its like an eCos but not an open sorce.